# How can i create a dynamic progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: desired image]

[image: what i'm getting]

I am trying to create a progress bar which looks like the first image above but end up getting the second image as a result.
I am using html, CSS and JavaScript. where did I get it wrong? Or is there something I am missing out?
the black dots are not really that important to me as I am interested in the shape of the progress bar

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".number");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if(counter == 65 ){
    clearInterval();
  }else{
    counter+=1;
    numb.textContent = counter + "%";
  }
}, 80);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  display:grid;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde6f0;
}
.circular{
  height:120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  transform:scale(2);
}
.circular .inner{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background: #dde6f0;
  border-radius: 100%;
 
}
.circular .number{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:10;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:500;
  color:#4158d0;
}
.circular .bar{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 120px, 120px, 70px);
}
.circle .bar .progress{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 70px, 120px, 0px);
  background: #FF6600;
}
.circle .left .progress{
  z-index:1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}
@keyframes left{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.circle .right {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index:3;
 
}
.circle .right .progress{
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay:4s;
}
@keyframes right{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circular">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="number">100%</div>
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="bar left">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar right">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with it until it worked.

Changed the clip on `.circular .bar` and `.circle .bar .progress` to

`clip: rect(0px, 120px, 120px, 60px);` and respectively `clip: rect(0px, 60px, 120px, 0);`

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".number");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if(counter == 65 ){
    clearInterval();
  }else{
    counter+=1;
    numb.textContent = counter + "%";
  }
}, 80);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  display:grid;
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde6f0;
}
.circular{
  height:120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  transform:scale(2);
}
.circular .inner{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background: #dde6f0;
  border-radius: 100%;
 
}
.circular .number{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index:10;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:500;
  color:#4158d0;
}

.circular .bar{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 120px, 120px, 60px);
}
.circle .bar .progress{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 60px, 120px, 0);
  background: #FF6600;
}
.circle .left .progress{
  z-index:1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}
@keyframes left{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.circle .right {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index:3;
 
}
.circle .right .progress{
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay:4s;
}
@keyframes right{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circular">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="number">100%</div>
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="bar left">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar right">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```